# Create a simple stored procedure IN mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying create a simple stored procedure in mysql, In this stored procedure I'm trying to call a view and page it.

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectSearchResultsContract (start int, quantity int)
BEGIN
    select

        searchresultsdisplayview.CompanyName,
        searchresultsdisplayview.LastChanceDate,
        searchresultsdisplayview.PhoneNumber,
        searchresultsdisplayview.ContactName,

        searchresultsdisplayview.City,
        searchresultsdisplayview.State


    FROM searchresultsdisplayview -- this is a view
    OFFSET start
    LIMIT quantity ;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

I cannot create this because of the syntax. says I'm missing a simicolon.
I have create many that we like this using tables but the view doesnt like it. Can someone please tell me what I am missing.

EXACT ERROR:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'start     LIMIT quantity' at line 15

[image: Added Picture]

Comment: I suspect that you need dynamic statement (store sql within a string and then execute it)

Comment: why would I need to use dynamic?

Comment: I think the problem is with variable substitution directly into the sql statement (start and quantity variables). I'm not 100% sure, but this is where I would look.

Comment: so removing the var, I still and the offset and limit I still get the same error.

Comment: I've always used `LIMIT _offset_, _rowcount_`, according to the docs, it looks like using the Postgres-compatibility `LIMIT _count_ OFFSET _offset_` should be done in that order. Does that query work if you paste it into a query browser like mysql workbench and replace the variables with literals?

Comment: @JamTay317 it is often helpful to include the exact error in the question

Comment: Please try to change it accordingly to @Uueerdo comment. Replace it with LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 for example.

Comment: I tried this and Got exact same error

Comment: Error must be different, there's no way :o At least the *to use near* part.

Comment: okay, so I right clicked and add stored procedure and it copy past and it worked, but why doesn't script work?

Comment: thank you everyone, I figured this out I will post answer.

Comment: This is because you had OFFSET before LIMIT and it should be the other way around :-)

Answer (score 0):

I Figured this out by right clicking and adding stored procedure then copy and paste the sql that it displayed. below is anwser:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `construction_bid_source`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SelectSearchResultsContract` (quantity int, start int)
BEGIN
    select

        searchresultsdisplayview.CompanyName,
        searchresultsdisplayview.LastChanceDate,
        searchresultsdisplayview.PhoneNumber,
        searchresultsdisplayview.ContactName,

        searchresultsdisplayview.City,
        searchresultsdisplayview.State


    FROM searchresultsdisplayview 
    LIMIT quantity-- this is a view
    OFFSET start;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```